# how to get code for already deployed contract in ethereum network

Tags: contract-development, abi

Let's say peer A is deployed a contract and exposes contract ABI. Peer B wants to join the same network.He have the ABI with him.But he wants to see the real contract code before joining the network.How peer B will be able to see that.

Comment: The contract code is included in the data field of the transaction that has created it.

Comment: The words "contract code" are a bit muddy. The 'byte code' is included in the `input` data field. I think the OP is asking about the Solidity 'source code'.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract

Answer (score 3):

Unless Peer A has made the source code available, you will only be able to see the byte code (i.e., the compiled code).

Even if Peer A makes the source code available, however, you should still be cautious. If Peer A was malicious, he/she may have published source code with an identical ABI, but with different code behind the interface.

For this reason, if you really want to be ultra secure, you should get the source code, read it until you become comfortable that it does what it is supposed to do, and then compile it yourself into byte code. Not until you've confirmed that the byte code that you've compiled yourself is identical to what is running at the smart contract's address can you be certain that you fully understand what will happen if you send ETH there.

For example, this is the Golem factory contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x7da82c7ab4771ff031b66538d2fb9b0b047f6cf9). As you can see, the source code has been "Verified." In this case, Etherscan performed the process I describe above, and you can be confident that the source and the byte code are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Peer A should have posted it at `GitHub.com/(TheRelevantRepositorySubdirectoryHere)`.

Otherwise, it is available on the block in question as bytecode. The EVM executes this bytecode when the contract is used: such as storing/changing data or using a `constant` function. Of course, there's always [bytecode to opcode converters.](https://etherscan.io/opcode-tool?a=0x9e1b57fc92eba6434251a8458811c32690f32c45)

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798205/how-to-get-or-verify-the-source-code-of-a-contract

Comment: Registering the contract code in Git holds good for public network.But if I am using private network what should we do then.

Comment: @BudhadityaDutta You need to get the code from that person directly. Otherwise, you'll just see the bytecode.