# How can i extract an activity name of a method signature from an ABI?

Tags: blockchain, abi, method

I am actually working for a research, I'm studying what happened in DAO Hack and I'm looking for some infos in the ABI of TheDarkDAO's smart contract. Exactly I am trying to understand how to discover the activity name behind a method signature from an ABI. I already tried to use [Ethereum Function Database](https://www.4byte.directory/) to search them but i found nothing. So, there is a question: How can i extract an activity name of a method signature from an ABI? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you clarify ? What do you mean by `activity name` ? Given your link, It feels like you are using `function signature` in place of function identifier and `activity name` in place of function signature, maybe I'm just misunderstanding though.

Comment: My bad, i mean text signature for activity name!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're trying to [decompile a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/188/85633). How can you do that? You can't.

Unless the creators of the smart contract *verified* the contract, it's not possible to decompile the bytecode into human-readable source code.

Here is the explanation of [smart contract verification](https://www.learninginverted.com/blog/smart-contract-verification). You might want to check if the smart contract is verified. If it is, it will look like this on Etherscan:

[image]